# How to make parameters change a function when calling it?

Tags: function, parameters, parameter-passing, processing

I want to create a function that can generate two balls that rise at different speeds. I used the parameters of the speed in which it rises called `change` and another parameter of its x coordinates called `x`, so that they don't originate from the same place. This is a code in processing, so the ellipse, size, fill, stroke, setup and draw functions are built in.

If I call the function, it works, and the ball moves according to the speed that I set. However, if I call the `risingball()` function twice, two balls are generated, but both move at the speed that is called with the second executed function. In this case, two balls were generated at x coordinates 150 and 450. The first ball was supposed to move at speed `y-10`, and the second ball at speed `y-5`, but both are moving at `y-5`.

Therefore, they move, but the whole purpose of the code which is making it change doesn't work.

```
void setup(){
  size(600,600);
}
float y = 600;

 void risingball(float change, float x){
  noStroke();
  fill(30,0,30);
  y = y-change;
  ellipse(x,y, 50,50);
}
  void draw(){
  background(255);
  risingball(10, 450);
  risingball(5, 250);
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like JavaScript code. Is that part of a Java class?

Answer (score 0):

Even though you're using the function **twice**, that function modifies the same **one** `y` variable:

```java
risingball(10, 450); // modifies y first
risingball(5, 250);  // modifies the same y again (when it shouldn't)
```

Because you want to move two balls at independent speeds you all need two independent `y` variables (one for each ball).

You could use two independent `y` variables but you'd also need to modify the function so it doesn't change the same data. One option could be using a y argument and returning the modified data:

```java
float y1 = 600;
float y2 = 600;

void setup(){
  size(600,600);
}

 float risingball(float change, float x, float y){
  noStroke();
  fill(30,0,30);
  y = y-change;
  ellipse(x,y, 50,50);
  return y;
}
  void draw(){
  background(255);
  y1 = risingball(10, 450, y1);
  y2 = risingball(5, 250, y2);
}
```

Another variant might be to simply use the function to render the ball, but keep the `y` variable updates outside the function:

```java
float y1 = 600;
float y2 = 600;

void setup(){
  size(600,600);
}

 void risingball(float x, float y){
  noStroke();
  fill(30,0,30);
  ellipse(x,y, 50,50);
}
  void draw(){
  // update data
  y1 = y1 - 10;
  y2 = y2 - 5;
  //render
  background(255);
  risingball(450, y1);
  risingball(250, y2);
}
```

Yet another option is using classes, though I'm not sure if you had a chance to play with these yet. Just in case:

```java
// RisingBall(float argX, float argY, float argChange, float argSize)
RisingBall ball1 = new RisingBall(450, 600, -10, 50);
RisingBall ball2 = new RisingBall(250, 600, -5, 50);

void setup(){
  size(600,600);
  noStroke();
  fill(30,0,30);
  
}

void draw(){
  background(255);
  ball1.updateAndDraw();
  ball2.updateAndDraw();
}

class RisingBall{
  
  float x;
  float y;
  float vy;
  
  float diameter;
  
  RisingBall(float argX, float argY, float argChange, float argSize){
    x = argX;
    y = argY;
    vy = argChange;
    diameter = argSize;
  }
  
  void updateAndDraw(){
    // update
    y += vy;
    // optional: reset Y
    if(y < -diameter){
      y = height;
    }
    // draw
    ellipse(x, y, diameter, diameter);
  }
  
}
```